# Sending Messages from Wildfly 13 to remote Artemis ActiveMQ

Tags: java, jms, wildfly, jndi, activemq-artemis

I am trying to connect a Wildfly 13 - Instance to a standalone Artemis ActiveMQ to produce and consume messages from it. Therefore I have followed the relevant parts of the [Wildfly 13 Documentation](http://docs.wildfly.org/13/Admin_Guide.html#Messaging_Connect_a_pooled-connection-factory_to_a_Remote_Artemis_Server) and [Artemis ActiveMQ Documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/1.1.0/using-jms.html#jndi-configuration). Furthermore, I tried to use [this](http://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/1.1.0/using-jms.html#jndi-configuration) tutorial and customized it a little bit using JMS 2.0 Simplified-API.

There is no Exception thrown when I am sending a payload to /produce. So I believe there is an issue with JNDI. I already monitored the ongoing network activity with [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and was able to see the package exchange between the Wildfly and the Artemis ActiveMQ. Wildfly constantly tries to access the remote queue but ends with

```
AMQ11901 7: Queue does not exist
```

Up until now, I could not figure out why this happens.

Here is what I have until now:

Wildfly Configuration (standalone-full-ha.xml)

```
//...
<outbound-socket-binding name="ImportantMessages-remote">
    <remote-destination host="127.0.0.1" port="61616"/>
</outbound-socket-binding>
//...
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:3.0">
    <server name="default">       
        <security-setting name="#">
            <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
        </security-setting>
        <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10" redistribution-delay="1000"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
        </http-connector>
        <remote-connector name="ImportantMessages-remote" socket-binding="ImportantMessages-remote"/>
        <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-connector>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
        </http-acceptor>
        <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-acceptor>
        <broadcast-group name="bg-group1" jgroups-cluster="activemq-cluster" connectors="http-connector"/>
        <discovery-group name="dg-group1" jgroups-cluster="activemq-cluster"/>
        <cluster-connection name="my-cluster" address="jms" connector-name="http-connector" discovery-group="dg-group1"/>
        <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
        <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
        <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
        <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector" ha="true" block-on-acknowledge="true" reconnect-attempts="-1"/>
        <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
        <pooled-connection-factory name="ImportantMessages-remote" entries="java:/jms/remoteIM" connectors="ImportantMessages-remote"/>
    </server>
</subsystem>
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
    <bindings>
        <external-context name="java:global/remoteContext" module="org.apache.activemq.artemis" class="javax.naming.InitialContext">
            <environment>
                <property name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"/>
                <property name="java.naming.provider.url" value="tcp://127.0.0.1:61616"/>
                <property name="queue.ImportantMessages" value="ImportantMessages"/>
            </environment>
        </external-context>
        <lookup name="java:/ImportantMessages" lookup="java:global/remoteContext/ImportantMessages"/>
    </bindings>
    <remote-naming/>
</subsystem>
```

MessageProducerRessource

```
@Stateless
@Path("produce")
public class MessageProducerResource {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MessageProducerResource.class.getName());

    @Inject
    @JMSConnectionFactory("java:/jms/remoteIM")
    private JMSContext jmsContext;

    @Resource(lookup = "java:global/remoteContext/ImportantMessages")
    private Queue queue;

    @POST
    public void sendMessage(String txt) {
        jmsContext.createProducer().send(queue, txt);
        LOG.info("Sent message containing \"" + txt + "\" to " + queue);
    }
}
```

I believe these are the relevant code snippets. If you need any further information, please do not hesitate to ask. Has anybody faced a similar issue and can help me out?

Comment: Please share the broker.xml from Artemis as well as the version of Artemis you're using.

Comment: Here is the [broker.xml](https://gist.github.com/jeremypuchta/086ed258c2e5fe9d3e49d5b81ea91c5b)! I am using version **2.6.2**.

Answer (score -1):

Probably u need to set security credentials on your artemis broker and add user/password to pooled-connection-factory.

```
<pooled-connection-factory name="ImportantMessages-remote" entries="java:/jms/remoteIM" connectors="ImportantMessages-remote" user="user123" password="Password123"/>
```